# Applying transformations at end of animation

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I've used the Blender rigid body simulator to position several mesh objects on the ground in a scene. Now that they are all in place, I'd like to keep them in their new positions when I remove their rigid body modifiers and set the animation slider back to zero. But when I remove the modifier from an object, it goes back to its original pre-animation position.

How do I clear the animation, but keep the objects in their new positions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Applying the "Visual Transform" of an object allows you to keep the current position/rotation/scale of the object and clear the accumulated Physics.  Or if your simulating mesh interactions (e.g., Cloth) use "Object :: Apply :: Visual Geometry to Mesh".

[Apply "Visual Transform"](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/scene_layout/object/editing/apply.html#visual-transform)

[image]

Comment: This did the trick. Many thanks!